# When is $G$, a finite group, the sum of its Sylow $p$-subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Questions like this have been asked before, but I just want some quick clarification on something.

Suppose that $G$ is the sum of its Sylow $p$-subgroups.  Then each Sylow subgroup must be normal, and of course we have the other direction.  If each Sylow subgroup is normal, then $G$ is the product of its Sylow subgroups.

My question that I need clarified is, "if $G$ is a sum of its Sylow subgroups, when will this be abelian, non-abelian?"

Comment: If by sum you mean direct product then iff $G$ is nilpotent

Comment: A remark: Direct sum is only defined for abelian groups. For finite abelian groups, direct sum is the same as direct product. See [Direct sum of finitely-many non-abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498830/direct-sum-of-finitely-many-non-abelian-groups) for generalization to nonabelian case.

Comment: Yes I realize that sum is used for abelian cases.  I really do mean product.

Comment: Thank you.  Nilpotent is what I am looking for.

Comment: To answer your last question, a direct product of subgroups is abelian if and only if each of those subgroups is abelian. So a finite nilpotent group is abelian if and only if all of its Sylow subgroups are abelian.